# I used a session with an error msg CS1001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

sorry to ask a simple question.

I used a session to store a variable in a controller, but an error code of CS1001 appears, would anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
Session.["StaffId"] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Session.["StaffId"] = 1;` should be like this `Session["StaffId"] = 1;` there is no need for `.` after session(forgive me if it is a typo)

Comment: @KeonVong: While looking at your profile, you have asked 12 questions and most of them were answered correctly but you have not marked anyone as accepted, So you should read [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and dont forget to mark an answer as accepted if that help s you.